# How to place a <div> tag after <td> in cgridview yii?

Tags: php, html, css, yii, cgridview

I want to fix the width of the columns generated using CGRIDVIEW. One way to do this is by adding a `<div>` tag after every `<td>` such that I can assign styling to that div. 
The Structure I am looking for is as such ==>

```
<td><div style='width:50px;'>$data['name']</div></td>
```

When I write this into the firebug .. I get the output as required... but now I need to code it....

View which holds GridView is ==>

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
            'type' => 'bordered striped',
            'id' => 'bike_search',   
            'dataProvider' => $model->search_bikes(),
            'ajaxUpdate' => true, //false if you want to reload aentire page (useful if sorting has an effect to other widgets)
            'filter' => null, 
            'template'=>'<div style="overflow:auto;">{items}</div>{pager}{summary}',
            'columns' => $selected_columns,
            'enablePagination' => true
        ));
```

The Model is ==>

```
$selected_columns[] = array(
                'header' => 'Name',
                'name' => 'name',
                'value'=>'$data["name"]', 

            );
```

How do I solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have array data provider you can use `$data["name"]` otherwise you have to use `$data->name` !

```
array(
        'header' => 'Name',
        'name' => 'name',
        'value'=> '"<div style=\"width:50px;\">" . $data["name"] . "</div>"', 
        //or
        'value'=> function($data){
            return '<div style="width:50px;">' . $data['name'] . '</div>';
        }
    )
```

Comment: I use array data provider , so I choosed $data['name'] ...and also i included 'type'=>'html' ... this gave me the EXACT OUTPUT !!!!  ...whn i did not use 'type'=>'html', it printed the <div> tag in the column cell.... sooo to add 'type'=>'html' is necessary . And Thanks for the Solution .,...  !!

Comment: ==> hi ...i came across a new issue ... its like i m exporting the cgridview results to a csv file ... but now i get these <div> tags printed into the csv file .... How to resolve this issue ??? any help ?